# ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.gis.django'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geodjango

I'm using postgres database for geodjango.
I have installed all required libraries: gdal, geos, proj4, postgis.
I'm using `virtualenv` too
However, I am getting this:

```
  Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.
  <locals>.wrapper at 0x7f0f3808cae8>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", 
  line 227, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in 
  inner_run
  autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", 
  line 250, in raise_last_exception
  six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft- 
  raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", 
  line 227, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, 
  in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", 
  line 85, in populate
  app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 
  120, in create
  mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-
  master/env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in 
  import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in 
  _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in 
  _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in 
  _find_and_load_unlocked
  ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.gis.django'
```

While including postgis in settings only error occurs or else it works well with postgresql database.

Comment: Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the entry in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. It should be:

```
'django.contrib.gis',
```

Comment: In that case, please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting as I asked

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'login.apps.LoginConfig',
    'django.contrib.gis.'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: You don't have have `'django.contrib.gis',`, you have `'django.contrib.gis.'` you are missing the comma and the trailing dot shouldn't be there.

Comment: thnks actually im new to these things...but now a new error rises

Comment: GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/home/sue/local/lib/libgdal.so'

Comment: to actually add this file called libgdal.so...i cant because its not there in my project folder

Comment: I can't help with that. You haven't provided enough information, and it looks like an unrelated issue.

Comment: GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geos-3.4.2/capi/libgeos_c.so'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/home/nandu/PycharmProjects/nimkraft-master/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gdal-1.11.2/libgdal.so'

Comment: these two i have added in my settings

Comment: but libgeos_c.so and libgdal.so doesnt exist in my project

Comment: As I said, I can't help with that. It looks like an unrelated issue.